# Avoiding duplicate coulmns after nullSafeJoin scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have use case wherein I need to join **nullable** columns. I am doing the same like this :

```
  def nullSafeJoin(leftDF: DataFrame, rightDF: DataFrame, joinOnColumns: Seq[String]) = {

    val dataset1 = leftDF.alias("dataset1")
    val dataset2 = rightDF.alias("dataset2")

    val firstColumn = joinOnColumns.head
    val colExpression: Column = (col(s"dataset1.$firstColumn").eqNullSafe(col(s"dataset2.$firstColumn")))

    val fullExpr = joinOnColumns.tail.foldLeft(colExpression) {
      (colExpression, p) => colExpression && (col(s"dataset1.$p").eqNullSafe(col(s"dataset2.$p")))
    }
    dataset1.join(dataset2, fullExpr)
  }
```

The final joined dataset has duplicate columns. I have tried dropping the columns using the alias like this :

```
dataset1.join(dataset2, fullExpr).drop(s"dataset2.$firstColumn")
```

but it doesn't work.
I understand that instead of dropping we can do a select columns.

I am trying to have a generic code base so don't want to pass the list of columns to be selected to the function (In case of drop I would be having to just drop the list of *joinOnColumns* we have passed to the function)

Any pointers on how to solve this would be really helpful.
Thanks!

Edit : (Sample data )

```
leftDF :
+------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
|                 A|          B|        C|        D| status|
+------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
|             14567|         37|        1|     game|Enabled|
|             14567|       BASE|        1|      toy| Paused|
|             13478|       null|        5|     game|Enabled|
|              2001|       BASE|        1|     null| Paused|
|              null|         37|        1|     home|Enabled|
+------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+

rightDF :
+------------------+-----------+---------+
|                 A|          B|        C|
+------------------+-----------+---------+
|               140|         37|        1|
|               569|       BASE|        1|
|             13478|       null|        5|
|              2001|       BASE|        1|
|              null|         37|        1|
+------------------+-----------+---------+

Final Join (Required):
+------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
|                 A|          B|        C|        D| status|
+------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
|             13478|       null|        5|     game|Enabled|
|              2001|       BASE|        1|     null| Paused|
|              null|         37|        1|     home|Enabled|
+------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data for leftDF,rightDF, joinColumns & expected output ?

Comment: what will be the values for this - joinOnColumns ?

Comment: Hi, 1st question why are you joining on all cols? Is that really necessary? And 2nd question, the final joined results should have the cols of the `leftDF`? If so you can just do `df1.join(df2, fullExpr).select(df1.columns.map(col))`

Comment: Hi, Not joining on all the columns. We are joining on only some of the columns. And we have to retain not just the leftDF columns but as well the ones on rightDF. Sorry if the example I have mentioned is a bit misleading.
So lets say:
`leftDF.columns -> (A,B,C,D,E,F) and rightDF.columns -> (A,B,C,X,Y). And we have join on (A,B,C) which are nullable. Now the finalDF should have (A,B,C,D,E,F,X,Y)` . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final DataFrame has duplicate columns from both leftDF & rightDF, don't have identifier to check if that column is from leftDF or rightDF.

So I have renamed leftDF & rightDF columns. leftDF columns starts with `left_[column_name]` & rightDF columns starts with `right_[column_name]`

Hope below code will help you.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  val left = Seq(("14567", "37", "1", "game", "Enabled"), ("14567", "BASE", "1", "toy", "Paused"), ("13478", "null", "5", "game", "Enabled"), ("2001", "BASE", "1", "null", "Paused"), ("null", "37", "1", "home", "Enabled")).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d", "status")
  val right = Seq(("140", "37", 1), ("569", "BASE", 1), ("13478", "null", 5), ("2001", "BASE", 1), ("null", "37", 1)).toDF("a", "b", "c")

  import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
  def nullSafeJoin(leftDF: DataFrame, rightDF: DataFrame, joinOnColumns: Seq[String]):DataFrame = {
    val leftRenamedDF = leftDF
      .columns
      .map(c => (c, s"left_${c}"))
      .foldLeft(leftDF){ (df, c) =>
        df.withColumnRenamed(c._1, c._2)
      }
    val rightRenamedDF = rightDF
      .columns
      .map(c => (c, s"right_${c}"))
      .foldLeft(rightDF){(df, c) =>
        df.withColumnRenamed(c._1, c._2)
      }

    val fullExpr = joinOnColumns
      .tail
    .foldLeft($"left_${joinOnColumns.head}".eqNullSafe($"right_${joinOnColumns.head}")){(cee, p) =>
        cee && ($"left_${p}".eqNullSafe($"right_${p}"))
      }

    val finalColumns = joinOnColumns
      .map(c => col(s"left_${c}").as(c)) ++ // Taking All columns from Join columns
      leftDF.columns.diff(joinOnColumns).map(c => col(s"left_${c}").as(c)) ++ // Taking missing columns from leftDF
      rightDF.columns.diff(joinOnColumns).map(c => col(s"right_${c}").as(c)) // Taking missing columns from rightDF

    leftRenamedDF.join(rightRenamedDF, fullExpr).select(finalColumns: _*)
  }

scala>
```

Final DataFrame result is :

```
scala> nullSafeJoin(left, right, Seq("a", "b", "c")).show(false)


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+-----+----+---+----+-------+
|a    |b   |c  |d   |status |
+-----+----+---+----+-------+
|13478|null|5  |game|Enabled|
|2001 |BASE|1  |null|Paused |
|null |37  |1  |home|Enabled|
+-----+----+---+----+-------+
```

Comment: No, its working I was saying we need not rename the columns of the dataframe since we have alias dataframe. 

So I added the logic of finding the list of columns to be selected using the alias based on the approach you have suggested.
Modified the snippet this way :
`
 val finalColumns = joinOnColumns .map(c => col(s"dataset1.${c}").as(c)) ++ // Taking All columns from Join columns leftDF.columns.diff(joinOnColumns).map(c => col(s"dataset1.${c}").as(c)) ++ // Taking missing columns from leftDF rightDF.columns.diff(joinOnColumns).map(c => col(s"dataset2.${c}").as(c)) 
`